# Is the name "Sadiqur Rahman" wrong in Islam?

Tags: names

My name is MD Sadiqur Rahman. My name contains 'Rahman' which is one of the name which only belongs to Allah. Is there anything wrong if someone calls me with this name?

Answer (score 3):

Please ask a language expert  what does "Sadiqur Rahman" mean?

I guess (maybe wrong) that it means "the truthful of Rahman", and so is maybe equivalent to "Abdul Rahman" which means "Slave of Rahman", so it can be permissible since you are not calling yourself Rahman but something of Rahman.

Answer (score 1):

Naming children with names such as Rahman, Jabbar, Allah, etc., which are specific to the essence of God, is not good, but naming names such as Hamid, Ali, etc. is not a problem.

Of course, if you add the word 'Abd' at the beginning of God's special names to convey the meaning of serving God, such as "Abdullah, 'Abd al-Jabbar, etc., naming a child after him is not only okay, but is recommended by the Ahl al-Bayt.

**Consequently, I think you'd better add the word "Abd" before Rahman, namely: Abd-Rahman (AbdulRahman)**

Reference: http://www.askquran.ir/showthread.php?t=57136

Comment: As Kiran said, I believe the name means Sadiq of Ar-Rahman. As such, it already seems similar to Abdur-Rahman.

Answer (score -2):

Ar-rahman is the second 'name' of ALLAH. However, all the 99 'names' of ALLAH are in fact properties of HIM. These are all good properties, self-speakingly. So, it's also good if we people, as far as we can and are supposed to, should also incorporate them to find the best possible oneness with the Highest.
Your name is a property that humans can thus should aim to have: to be gracious , French miséricordieux is a better fit. Ar-rahmani is exative, (of) the Most Gracious. Your name is only 'gracious'. In that sense you can accept it with honour and respect.
Off cause the name ALLAH itself is the proper name,  there only Abdullah,  servant of ALLAH is possible.

Comment: Is my name permissable to use? In your opinion?

Comment: This answer is deficient. The view of many scholars is that "Ar-Rahman" is among the unique names of God and it is forbidden to give it to someone else. That is because of its usage in-place of "Allah" such as in [17:110](https://quran.com/17/110), [13:30](https://quran.com/13/30), [25:60](https://quran.com/25/60), [43:15](https://quran.com/43/45), and in [Surah Maryam](https://legacy.quran.com/19/), further it has been cited as the name meant in one exegesis of [19:65](https://quran.com/19/65?translations=84).

Comment: That's what I said: "Ar-Rahman" = "**The** Gratious" is the Name of God, whereas "rahman" as such is an adjective.

Comment: The same applies to the other names, for example Malik (as we know, it's the name of the famous teacher, but also a common given name). So, as your name is simply Rahman, I do not see any Problem to  use it.

Comment: It is also forbidden to name someone Rahman without the *Al* prefix, as it is a specific name of Allah, قال الأزهري ولا يجوز أن يقال رحمن إلا لله عز وجل  ([Lisan al-Arab](https://al-maktaba.org/book/34077/6146#p1)). Musaylimah the liar called himself رحمن اليمامة and was condemned for it. Also for this question specifically, the name "Sadiq**ur** Rahman" includes 'the'.

Comment: @UmH First of all I want to say that I appreciate very much your answers coming out of a vast knowledge. Still, as it's the question whether Sadiqur may use his name, where, as I have understood, Rahman is not even the given name but the family name. I have not been aware that in spoken language it sounds equal to the name of God. Written, however, isn't it an ending r space thus different. Finally Lisan al-Arab is a dictionary not even a fatwa. I still believe that limiting the use of all words in the 99 names of ALLAH is not the right way because many of them are something we should reach.